# detail band spanning multiple pages

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using ireports 5.0.1. I have a detail band which is very large (height 2313). After exporting to PDF , the generated file is not suitable for printing . How to span the band over multiple pages? (just 2 pages will do)

Comment: What do you mean with "the generated file is not suitable for printing" ?

Comment: the height of the generated pdf is very large. so when printing , the fontbecomes smaller.

Comment: actually we are printing an A1 sized page in A4 page......that's why i think the font is smaller

Comment: If your problem is about the size of the report then you can modify the page size of the report in the report's properties.

Comment: that's the problem , i want to split the band over 2 pages. i cant change the page size, because there are lots of fixed sized frames in the band.

Comment: Do you mind setting a page break ?

Answer (score 3):

A band's maximum height is the height of the page without top and bottom margin, a split of a single band over multiple pages is not possible. Depending on your report design you might add a second detail band and move items for the second page there. In order to enforce a page break you can utilize a page break element.